# Laravel Multi Tenant considers www part as subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, web, subdomain, multi-tenant

I am building a multi tenant system in laravel and each subdomain is saved in database. When a subdomain in visited, it is checked from the database either it exists or not, if it doesn't exists then abort(403) is called. Following is the way:

Routes/web.php

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.example.com', 'middleware' => ['Subdomain']), function () {

    Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');
}
```

Middleware/Subdomain.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Subdomains::where('subdomain', $request->subdomain)->count()==0){
        return abort(403);
    }else{
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

But when I visit [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), then www is also considered as subdomain and checked from database, since it doesn't exist in database and abort(403) is also called for it. In short my website is not visited with [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) URL.

Is there any way to differentiate www form other subdomains in this Laravel multi tenancy system or any way to handle this thing?

Comment: Consider setting up a www --> no-www redirect at the server level.

Comment: @ceejayoz , yes I have did that in the .htaccess file , but when the url is https;// www,example.com it still takes me to the subdomain check, but yes it work good for HTTP_HOST (http;//www.example.com)

Comment: It's a server thing: https://yoast.com/how-to-remove-www-from-your-url/

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `if` statement to check if the subdomain queried is **www**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  if($request->subdomain != 'www') {
    if(Subdomains::where('subdomain', $request->subdomain)->count()==0){
        return abort(403);
    }else{
        return $next($request);
    }
  }
}
```

Also in your .htaccess, remove www from the domain name

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you @Clement Sam, for your kind response, but return $next($request) part still takes it to the subdomain part, it just now removing the database check

Comment: You can aslo use .htaccess to remove www from the url